# Vectordrawable blurry bitmap on ImageView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable, android-support-design

I created a custom view that extends ImageView. When I set the vector drawable whose viewport is smaller, I am noticing that image is blurry.
If I just use the ImageView, I am seeing the vector image is sharp as it is suppose to be.

In my custom view I override "setImageDrawable", where I do call super and then get bitmap from the drawable to paint later in `onDraw`.

Here is how i am converting to bitmap

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
         Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get view width and height, not the drawable, and use these as the drawable bounds. I assume your view dimension might change over time so this is not a one time task. I would store the drawable in a member field:

```
   private Drawable drawable;

   @Override
   public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
       this.drawable = drawable;
       this.drawable.setBounds(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
       // invalidate if needed
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int wms, int hms) {
       super.onMeasure(wms, hms);
       if (drawable != null) drawable.setBounds(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
   }
```

Then onDraw, just draw the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Just do drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*5(any num.), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*5 and pass DisplayMatrices in first parameter, it will increase the quality.

---

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*5,
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*5,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```